# DefaultBackend always unhealthy using Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gcp-load-balancer

I tried to modify this sample: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk
to make the wordpress service available behind an Ingress HTTPS LoadBalancer.
But it does not work as expected. Backend is always unhealthy.
I am using a version 1.25.8-gke.500 auto-pilot cluster. (A weird notification: "Can’t scale up due to exceeded quota" -> could be from that ?)

Do you have any idea or a hint of what I am missing ?

Regards,
Olivier

Here is the manifest:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: wordpress-volumeclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - www.jaijai.io
    - jaijai.io
---
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: networking-fc
spec:
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: true
    responseCodeName: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: http-hc-config
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 60
    port: 80
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /health
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: wordpress
          name: wordpress
          env:
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
            value: 127.0.0.1:3306
          # These secrets are required to start the pod.
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: username
          - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/www/html
        # Change jaijai-admin:europe-west1:mysql-wordpress-instance here to include your GCP
        # project, the region of your Cloud SQL instance and the name
        # of your Cloud SQL instance. The format is
        # ::
        - name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.33.2
          command: ["/cloud_sql_proxy",
                    "-instances=jaijai-admin:europe-west1:mysql-wordpress-instance=tcp:3306",
                    # If running on a VPC, the Cloud SQL proxy can connect via Private IP. See:
                    # https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip for more info.
                    # "-ip_address_types=PRIVATE",
                    "-credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/key.json"]
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 2  # non-root user
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
              mountPath: /secrets/cloudsql
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: wordpress-volumeclaim
        - name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: cloudsql-instance-credentials
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  namespace: default
  annotations: 
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "http-hc-config"}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: managed-cert-ingress
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: networking-fc
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: jaijai-frontend-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: wordpress
      port:
        number: 80
```

This is what I have from the console:

```
kubectl describe ingress managed-cert-ingress
Name:             managed-cert-ingress
Labels:           app=wordpress
Namespace:        default
Address:          35.244.233.172
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  wordpress:80 (10.98.128.68:80)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *           *     wordpress:80 (10.98.128.68:80)
Annotations:  ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: mcrt-a0143225-6a2f-4313-b1be-7f1ec913eb24
              ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {"k8s1-0d3ba664-default-wordpress-80-239e60bb":"UNHEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s2-fs-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s2-ts-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-url-map: k8s2-rm-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: mcrt-a0143225-6a2f-4313-b1be-7f1ec913eb24
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
              kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: jaijai-frontend-ip
              networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: managed-cert
              networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: networking-fc
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age                  From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                 ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       94s                  loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6" created
  Normal  Sync       90s                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6" created
  Normal  Sync       76s                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6" created
  Normal  IPChanged  76s                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now 35.244.233.172
  Normal  Sync       68s                  loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-ts-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6" created
  Normal  Sync       55s                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fs-v4g4jvrr-default-managed-cert-ingress-dwceqex6" created
  Normal  Sync       52s (x6 over 2m24s)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

What I tried to solve this:

- Changing the wordpress deployment with a helloword container works well (not what I want).
- Using wordpress with a loadbalancer service works also well (not what I try to do).
- Added healthcheck with backend-config
- Added neg annotation
- tried both ClusterIP and NodePort

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl describe deployment wordpress`?